# SharpDX multi-threading inside the game toolkit

Tags: multithreading, toolkit, sharpdx

I'm looking for an example of multi-threading implementation inside the game toolkit? I have the MultiCube example, but that is for WinForms and I use WPF, and I can't use the game toolkit tools from Direc3D11 because I need an instance of the GraphicsDevice. The MultiCube example is not displaying anything but a black screen, I tried it on several computers. My video card doesn't support command lists, don't know if that has anything to do with it. I was wondering how many models can SharpDX handle, because I have to draw hundreds of small 
scaffold couplers, and after adding about a 100 on the default GraphicsDevice, the application slows down and gets locked. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Haris

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing but I couldn't find any examples. I tried converting the MultiCube example to use the toolkit and got it basically working, still very messy at the moment and needs optimizing, but at least it renders.

https://github.com/PlehXP/SharpDX-Samples/tree/MultiCubeToolkit/Toolkit/WindowsDesktop/MultiCube